# Amount of connections are more then it may

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my play application and the database.
My postgresql server has a max connections of 150 and i have 5 applications running.

The db config looks like this:

```
db.default.partitionCount=3
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
```

So every play application should only have 15 connections, with makes a total of 75 connection. But when the applications have run a curtain amount of time. The total connection count is starting to exceed the max connections of postgresql.

When I look what kind of connections are still open, they are all idle. Does any one know a solution, or maybe some pointer?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your application takes a connection from database and not releasing it.
Firstly you should check and be sure that if your code is releasing connection after business logic is done.
Also for more stable architecture between application and database , I don't know if you are using or not but connection pooling is a good solution.
You can choose [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [pgbouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) for connection pooling.

Comment: If the application is holding the connection, won't the connection be in a state other then idle?

Comment: No it can be idle, till you release the connection it doesnt matter if it is in use or not.

Comment: But how can i controll the connection in Play. I use the JPA.em() method for all my queries. Isn't this setup so you don't have to open and close every time when you run a query.